# PhpStorm unable to recognize the Php File

Tags: php, laravel-5, phpstorm

I have a PHP trait file : `app\Lib\someTrait.php`

Even though it is a PHP file (with .php extension), PHPStorm is unable to recognize it as a valid PHP file. The editor is not doing syntax highlighting for PHP code inside this file and it is pretty much displayed as normal text file.

I am trying to use this file from its namespace in to another class file and there also it is unable to recognize the file path using :

```
use app\Lib\someTrait;
```

I did `composer dump-autoload` and also :

```
File->Invalid Caches and restart
```

I also deleted this file and restarted PHPStorm and again added it back but still not able to resolve this issue.

Looks like something has gone weird when I created a first file with this file name and now even though I tried all option PHPStorm is not treating this file as PHP file.

But still PHPStorm is unable to recognize this file.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: It _does_ have an open php tag (`<?php`), _right_? And does your code actually work, but PhpStorm is complaining for no good reason?

Comment: Yes it has `<?php` tag. And if I rename this file to another php file name  then no issue.

Comment: "does your code actually work, but PhpStorm is complaining for no good reason?"

Comment: Try moving it to another location, see if that works. If works, then it's probably the file name that's the issue.

Comment: As I mentioned...there is no error in code...if I just rename the file then it starts the syntax highlighting. So confirming that it is a fileName. How do I reset something so that everything goes back to normal. Why does PhpStorm not allowing me to use a specific filename and not recognizing it as a valid php file?

Comment: So then I fixed this now by renaming this file to a different filename in the PhpStorm... syntax highlighting started working ... then in Finder I renamed it back to original file name (I am on MAC) and then refreshing the PHPStorm ... it then recognized it as valid PHP. What the heck is wrong with PHPStorm ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155976/discussion-between-david-and-andy).

Comment: BTW .. my final solution is that I have renamed the file. Moving the file with the same name in different folder does not work either.  It appears to be some PhpStorm Index cache issue... or may be something else. Do not have a luxury to spend too much time on this.

Comment: Please post a screenshot or how the file looks in IDE (whole editor tab please). I'm interested in file icon + a bit of content. So far it sounds like common user misconfiguration when user does not pay attention to what happens on the screen. If I'm right -- no clearing caches etc will help and you will have the same issue in another project (with the same file name). So it's better just solve it right and not looking for "workarounds"

Comment: @lazyone: Unfortunately, there is not much I am allowed to share because of IP issues. But I have given all the details as much as I can.

Comment: Oh .. so file icon in IDE is an "IP issue"? Sorry about my request for details then. You seem to be happy with your workaround (got it working one way or another) .. so no problem here any more I guess.

Comment: Are you sure it is `app` namespace instead of `App` ?

Comment: @LazyOne The icon is showing as PHP file on the left plane. I will try to upload the icon (I have a certain theme installed). What I thought was that you want a complete image of editor.

Comment: @ matiaslauriti  The folder can be `app` but namespace can be `App` as per my knowledge. And I have other files (php traits) that I have in this folder which are working file with this namespace. So namespace is not an issue.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

File | Settings | Editor | File Types - search for that file (someTrait.php) in a "Text" file type. Once found - remove

Comment: Simple but not so easily to think like a first problem ;) +1

I had a same problem with "Tools.php" file in PrestaShop.

Comment: Right on the money! I wonder how the *Trait.php got there in the first place.

Comment: I added it by mistake into the ``Auto-detect file type by content`` category. Needless to say it was half an hour quite productive.

Answer (score 0):

for me works: File -> Manage IDE Settings -> Restore to Default Settings